# Visual Basic 2010, finishing your project by getting the exe file from bin, or publishing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, project, publishing

ok so i made a couple of projects in VB2010 and i want to finally make them a standalone executable , as i'm still a beginner in VB ! i don't know if getting the .exe file only from "bin/debug" or i should really publish it then need the applications folder and the setup [because it's gonna be a lot better if i don't have to do the second one], anyways i tried to get the exe file then move the project folder to another drive , and it work , i know that to run the exe in other computer i'll need framework , [as far as i know my resource files are embedded into the exe] but if i need framework only , i guess runing it on computers that doesn't have it will ask them to download it ! i don't mind that , or that option comes with publish ,and i also really need the manifest file to run it normally ,
**I actually don't know much about this so can you pleas tell me what i exactly need so my .exe files can run on other computers**
sorry for taking some of your time , and thank you for reading this :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `Solution Configurations` to `Release`, build a solution (Ctrl+Shift+B) then navigate to your `bin/Release` folder and there you will find your exe file ready to be shipped. You can ship that exe as is, or you can wrapp it up in an installer application. If your application has some dependencies then shipping the exe file will not be enough.

Comment: after i did the publish thing , i got in the Application files folder two dll files, i guess they're both related to windows media player, i may drop them if they're causing a problem , but are you sure that the exe only is gonna ask for framework if not installed ?

Comment: Generated DLL files in the `obj\x86\Release\TempPE` folder are not relevant when deploying. You need to implement functionality that will check if the framework is installed. There will be an exception if you try to run your vb.net application on a computer without the .NET framework.

Comment: i know that all my vb.net applications need .NET framework , i actually reworked on my project to use only the .NET components , what i want to know is that if i take my exe application and run it on a computer without .net framework  is a window saying something like ".NET framework need to be installed"? i don't care about anything else

Comment: and Also, if that's the only problem ,it's easy i will make a .. let's say vbscript that checks if .net framework 4.0 is installed [i actually made one , 18 lines only]  then i'll compile it to .exe, and do some binding stuff and have it similar to the functionality you talked about :D

Answer (score 1):

You can change your target framework by goin' to `Project/Properties`.
Find the .exe in `\\Your app\bin\debug\your app.exe`

Comment: i know i can target multiple framework versions , but that's not the problem ,the problem is that do i need the .manifest, .config , .xml files so that my exe can run properly ?

Comment: If you debug it, it will compile into that one exe

Answer (score 1):

What you can do,open the project as if going to edit it, just go to "Project" then "Publish(*Whatever-your-work's-name-is*).vb at the bottom. Then use the wizard to finish. At the end, say you saved your exe on the desktop, three files will appear.

1. *"Whatever-your-work's-name-is".exe* And its icon shape varies.
2. A folder called *"Application Files"*
3. And a *"setup.exe"* Its icon a like a CD on something.

For the first time, click on *setup.exe* and open the app. From then on, the *"Whatever-your-work's-name-is".exe* will open normally. I have a website where I publish these things for fun, "tgamer.myfreesites.net", and downloading will only download all three in a zipped folder. The website is not awesome, but it's alright.

The thing is, the setup.exe and application files can be in a zipped file. You only the actual exe from the second opening and onward. This option makes it downloadable, like what I want. For you, choose the best for you, but remember downloading only the exe will not work.